# mysql max query then JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, max

I have followed the tutorial over at tizag for the MAX() mysql function and have written the query below, which does exactly what I need. The only trouble is I need to JOIN it to two more tables so I can work with all the rows I need.

```
    $query = "SELECT idproducts, MAX(date) FROM results GROUP BY idproducts ORDER BY MAX(date) DESC";
```

I have this query below, which has the JOIN I need and works:

```
       $query =     ("SELECT * 
                    FROM operators
                    JOIN products
                    ON operators.idoperators = products.idoperator JOIN results
                    ON products.idProducts = results.idproducts 
                    ORDER BY drawndate  DESC
                    LIMIT 20");
```

Could someone show me how to merge the top query with the JOIN element from my second query? I am new to php and mysql, this being my first adventure into a computer language I have read and tried real hard to get those two queries to work, but I am at a brick wall. I cannot work out how to add the JOIN element to the first query :(

Could some kind person take pity on a newb and help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    operators
    JOIN products
        ON operators.idoperators = products.idoperator 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            idproducts, 
            MAX(date) 
        FROM results 
        GROUP BY idproducts 
    ) AS t
    ON products.idproducts = t.idproducts
ORDER BY drawndate  DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I have it working, thank you so much! Where can I read up which explains what you have done?

Comment: You have joined all operators with the assigned products. Then you get all results which have the most recent date for each product and join it to the assigned products.

Comment: Yeh I had to delete that bit to get it to work. I thank you so much!

Comment: @Dee1983: The subselect returning the max dates is also called a *derived table* in this context. I think, googling for that term (possibly, in combination with *mysql*) should give you some relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

JOINs function somewhat independently of aggregation functions, they just change the intermediate result-set upon which the aggregate functions operate. I like to point to the way the MySQL documentation is written, which hints uses the term 'table_reference' in the [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), and expands on what that means in [JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Basically, any simple query which has a table specified can simply expand that table to a complete JOIN clause and the query will operate the same basic way, just with a modified intermediate result-set.

I say "intermediate result-set" to hint at the mindset which helped me understand JOINS and aggregation. Understanding the order in which MySQL builds your final result is critical to knowing how to reliably get the results you want. Generally, it starts by looking at the first row of the first table you specify after 'FROM', and decides if it might match by looking at 'WHERE' clauses. If it is not immediately discardable, it attempts to JOIN that row to the first JOIN specified, and repeats the "will this be discarded by WHERE?". This repeats for all JOINs, which either add rows to your results set, or remove them, or leaves just the one, as appropriate for your JOINs, WHEREs and data. This process builds what I am referring to when I say "intermediate result-set". Somewhere between starting and finishing your complete query, MySQL has in it's memory a potentially massive table-like structure of data which it built using the process I just described. Only then does it begin to aggregate (GROUP) the results according to your criteria.

So for your query, it depends on what specifically you are going for (not entirely clear in OP). If you simply want the MAX(date) from the second query, you can simply add that expression to the SELECT clause and then add an aggregation spec to the end:

```
SELECT *, MAX(date)
FROM operators
 ...
GROUP BY idproducts
ORDER BY ...
```

Alternatively, you can add the JOIN section of the second query to the first.

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `SELECT *, MAX(date)` may be not ideal for beginners. You should know what you do if use this. I do it dirty too sometimes, but it is better to group all columns treated in the projection or use aggregate functions.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for the comment. I actually like (to some extent) that most other RDBMSs will not allow an aggregate query to select a column without an aggregate function.

Comment: But for MySQL the performance is sometimes better even it is dirty ;-)

Comment: Yes, which is why I wish SQL had an aggregate function such as FIRST() or LAST(), like MySQL's default behavior in this case (i.e. don't attempt any aggregation, just give me the first or last row's value for this column in the result-set.